# bombarding Electrons into the nucleus!

Tags: electrons, scattering, microscopy

Recently, in a workshop on Electron microscopy, our professor asked us a question over the backscattering of electron. his question goes like this "Why doesn't this electron falls straight into the nucleus, why is it back-scattered, what stops this e from falling into the nucleus ?"
[image]

We argued by providing him with Sun and Comet analogy, but he says something is still missing.

Comment: Maybe he wants you to discuss the effect of electrons moving around the nucleus on the incoming electron.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the math for gravity and for the Coulomb force are the same. Rutherford's analysis of backscattering of alpha particles works just fine for comets, alphas, and electrons.

Comment: @JonCuster I would say it is different here from Rutherford's experiment. In that experiment the alpha particles are heavy, thus a electron has minimal effect on its movement. Here the incoming particle is electron itself, not heavier than other electrons around the nucleus. Thus it's movement can't be like a comet around a sun.

Comment: @verdelite - depends on the energy of the incoming electron. Electron backscattering is quite common and used for diffraction (EBSD). Or, one could use an isolated fully-stripped ion for fun...

Comment: The factor would seem to me to be just a low probability of a direct collision. The nucleus has a very small cross-section. The electron has "escape velocity" so the electrostatic attraction of the nucleus can't slow the electron down enough to attract it. Thus only a direct hit would result in the electron and the nucleus meeting.

Comment: Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention about incoming electrons is that they are actually following a helical path since they are accelerated through electromagnetic field.

Comment: To be specific that time he was discussing about TEM

Answer (score -1):

S-electrons *do* fall into the nucleus. They have a finite probability there, the so called contact density. They don't remain there because of their high kinetic energy.

Comment: This answer is not incorrect. It may not be fair to down-vote it.

Comment: I agree. But my doubt is different.  Thanking everyone for their efforts